# How to avoid yawning in public?

Tags: sleeping

I was recently scolded by a teacher for yawning in class. If there is any other time when I feel the urge to yawn, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Not sure why so many downvotes. This seems like a useful problem to have a lifehack with.

Comment: @Demisemihemidemisemiquaver probably the downvotes were cast for the first revision of the question which wasn't really good. Now it's a fair score of 3. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are about to yawn **just touch the tongue with one of your fingers.**

The saltiness does the magic; it's highly unlikely that someone will carry salt in pocket, but a finger does the trick.

That's my hack for preventing a yawn. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Brilliant idea, but won't people look oddly at someone touching their own tongue? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a deep breath right before the yawn hits. It takes some alertness to anticipate the yawn, but this is the least conspicuous solution I've found.